# How to programmatically click a button and pass arguments using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments, click, frontend

I am building a frontend page using jQuery. I wish to programmatically click a button and send some arguments to the jQuery function of the button.

The id of the button is "btnAdd".
On clicking it, the jQuery function invoked is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", { value: sizes }, function(event) {
        console.log(event.data.value);
    });
});
```

I am programmatically clicking the button and passing arguments using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sel").change(function() {
        var sizes= ['11','12'];
        $("#btnAdd").click();
    });
});
```

This code is clicking the button but not passing the arguments.
What could be the error ?

Comment: It probably has something to do with the scope. Looks like you're defining the `sizes` variable inside the `.change` function, so the bind event likely doesn't have access to the variable. What does the `console.log` output?

Comment: It says: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: sizes is not defined' for the line :
'$("#btnAdd").bind("click", { value: sizes }, function(event) {'

Comment: Yea so thats the problem. You're defining sizes inside the `.change` function, so the `.bind` doesn't have access to it. You need to define it outside of any functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `trigger(event, data)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnAdd").on("click", function(event, data) {
    if (data) {
      console.log('Data sent', data.sizes);
    }else{
      console.log('No data')
    }
  });
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sel").change(function() {
    var sizes = ['11', '12'];
    $("#btnAdd").trigger('click', {sizes: sizes});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAdd">click me</button>
<br/>
<label>Check to send data <input type="checkbox" id="sel" /></label>
```